# Create Excel link to external Excel file from formula

Tags: excel, document, spreadsheet

I have a heap of files I need to reference in one central "dashboard" of sorts as an Excel file.

Right now, each page of the dashboard is manually coded, cell by cell and links to results from result spreadsheets from each of 5 people with 15 different fields for each. The fields each reference the same cell in the source excel document.

I'd like to remove the manual update side of things as each month rolls by by referencing the content directly. Here's one cell's reference:

```
='https://sharepointurl.tld/directory/Reporting/AgentName/[2014-05-May.xlsm]data'!$B$15
```

I would like to be able to reference this link this:

```
A = https://sharepointurl.com/directory/Reporting/ (prefix URL, hard coded)
B = AgentName (Agent name, referenced from $B$2)
C = /[2014 05 May.xlsm] (file name, referenced from $B$25)
D = data'! (worksheet, referenced from $B$26)
E = $B$1 (cell reference, referenced from $B$27)
```

Whereby something like:

```
ABCDE
```

Which I would enter like:

```
='https://sharepointurl.com/directory/Reporting/$B$2&$B$25&$B$26&$B$27'
```

Would result in:

```
='https://sharepointurl.tld/directory/Reporting/AgentName/[2014-05-May.xlsm]data'!$B$15
```

And therefore, it would display in the table with the contents of that cell, being:

```
17.54%
```

I'm sure this can be done, but I just can't seem to figure this out.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Directly by Excel function:

```
=HYPERLINK("https://sharepointurl.com/directory/Reporting/" &B2&B25&B26&B27;"https://sharepointurl.com/directory/Reporting/" &B2&B25&B26&B27)
```

Using VBA:

```
Public Function Hyper() As String
Dim Tmp As String
Dim xx As String

Application.Volatile
Debug.Print a

Tmp = "https://sharepointurl.com/directory/Reporting/" & Range("B2").Value & Range("B25").Value & Range("B26").Value & Range("B27").Value
xx = Application.Caller.Address

Range(xx).Hyperlinks(1).Address = Tmp
Hyper = Tmp
End Function
```

You can cerate a function that build a Dynamic Hyperlink.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to get a specific cell from the workbook you are linking to. In that case, put the URL string you created inside the INDIRECT() function. eg.

```
=INDIRECT("'https://sharepointurl.com/directory/Reporting/"&$B$2&$B$25&$B$26&$B$27)
```

Note that the hard-coded portion of the URL needs to be surrounded by `""` concatenated with the cell references with an `&`. No `'` is needed at the end.